# Color temp changes depending on content

Tags: screen, screen-brightness, color

I have a OnePlus 6 and recently (past few months) I've noticed the color temp changing between a "warm" white and a more "pure" (not the bluish "cool") white.

You can't see it in the screenshots (because the phone doesn't see the difference), but I get the yellower temp with

[image]

and the whiter one with

[image]

The difference is the ad at the top of the first one.  When that scrolls into view, it goes yellow. When is scrolls out of view, it goes white.  (If I need to, I can record it with another phone.)

I have night mode, reading mode, "vibrant color effect," and adaptive brightness all turned off.

I'm quite confused, and it's really annoying.  Any ideas how I can get it to stop?

Comment: Most likely this is the night (shift) mode which reduces the blue color brightness on screen to don't disturb your "sleep hormone" [melatonine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melatonin). Typically the night mode is (de)activated automatically based on sunset/sundown (calculated for your position).

Comment: This happens dynamically. In this case, the ad scrolled into view and it went yellow, out of view and it went white.  It's very reproducible.  And as I mentioned, I have night mode, etc., turned off.